# how to write xpath for this particular HTML

Tags: java, selenium

This is my code i am not able to find the xpath for this code please help me

```
<select class="review form-control pull-right" style="height:25px;padding:2px 5px;margin-right: 5px;">
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=author" name="author">Author Review</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=authorrevision" name="authorrevision">Author Revision</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=copyeditor" name="copyeditor">Copyeditor Review</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=feature" name="feature">Feature Review</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=publishercheck" name="publishercheck">Publisher Check</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=publisher" name="publisher">Publisher Review</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=readyforpub" name="readyforpub">Ready for Publication</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=typesetter" name="typesetter">Typesetter QA</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=typesettervalidation" name="typesettervalidation">Post Author Validation</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=digest" name="digest">Digest check</option>
    <option link="/review_content/article/80792?reviewer=preediting" name="preediting">Pre-editing</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is a single html tag. What is the XPath you're looking for supposed to do?

Comment: .//*[@id='80782']/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[1]/select

Comment: That is an XPath expression. How does this relate to the question? Is the ``select`` tag the result of that expression?

Comment: `//select` Perhaps this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Can you be little more specific about your query? Which element you want to locate? If you are trying to locate dropdown , you can use `//Select[@class = 'review form-control pull-right']`

Answer (score 0):

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='YOURTEXT']"));

Try above